# Linq join query displayed in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I'm trying to display a linq join query in a partial web view.

Here is my query within my controller:

```
public ActionResult InactiveUsers()
        {
            using (ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer())
            {
                DateTime duration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);

                var inactive = from usrs in ctn.aspnet_Users
                               where usrs.LastActivityDate <= duration
                               join o in ctn.Groups on
                               usrs.UserId equals o.UserID
                               select new
                               {
                                   usrs.UserName,
                                   usrs.LastActivityDate,
                                   o.PrimaryPhoneNumber,
                               };

                return View(inactive.ToList());
            }

        }
```

What I'm a bit confused on is what to do next. I'm familiar with adding strongly typed views using models, but what happens in my case where I have a join query?

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning an IEnumerable of anonymous types, you could create a class for the join result and then create a model for it as normal:

```
            var inactive = from usrs in ctn.aspnet_Users
                           where usrs.LastActivityDate <= duration
                           join o in ctn.Groups on
                           usrs.UserId equals o.UserID
                           select new InactiveUser(usrs.UserName, usrs.LastActivityDate, o.PrimaryPhoneNumber);
```

With an InactiveUser class which has a constructor which takes a UserName, Date and PhoneNumber.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Did what you said and now it works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use the "[ViewModel](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes)" pattern.  Instead of creating an anonymous type create a view model that contains the data you want to display. Simply populate that and pass it to your view.

> When using this pattern we create
>   strongly-typed classes that are
>   optimized for our specific view
>   scenarios, and which expose properties
>   for the dynamic values/content needed
>   by our view templates. Our controller
>   classes can then populate and pass
>   these view-optimized classes to our
>   view template to use. This enables
>   type-safety, compile-time checking,
>   and editor intellisense within view
>   templates.